# How can I change blogger default favicon

Tags: blogger, favicon

I want to change the default favicon for blogger.
In the last version, I can access the Layout tab and find it like this:
[image]
However, now I can't see the place to change the default favicon.
Please tell me how. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find it in the Settings > Basic > Favicon

[image: a screenshot of the Settings]

The link leads to the Configure Favicon screen.

[image: a screenshot of the Configure Favicon]